# How to extract and read swap call data from 0x quote API

Tags: 0x

I'm currently working on a new decentralised derivatives exchange and I'm considering using 0x protocol to perform swaps. In order to create market orders on chain I'm following this example [here](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/ef8d7a064209e57a91a7eb8b55119b97cd611c94/contracts/SimpleTokenSwap.sol#L65).

The example works for me however I would like to be able to access the `swapCallData` parameters from my smart contract as I'd like to do some validations before using it.

Is there a way to extract each field from `swapCallData` in js or solidity ? Is there a reference somewhere on the structure and content of this data, and is it guaranteed to always follow the same structure ?

Answer (score 1):

The swap call data is an ever changing encoding so having this hardcoded in a smart contract will ultimately break.

The reason behind this is, over time, we optimize the call data to perform cheaper swaps for the user.

You could use and update the [IZeroEx artifact](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-artifacts/artifacts/IZeroEx.json) to read this in javascript.